# Doubt regarding derivation of general expression of angular momentum of circular orbits

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, angular-momentum, orbital-motion

The Newtonian angular momentum $J$ of a circular orbit for a gravitational potential $\Phi$ is given by the relation (eqn. 10 of [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1093/mnras/stac2846))
$$J=\left(r^3\dfrac{d\Phi}{dr}\right)^{1/2}.$$

For the Newtonian potential $\Phi=-\frac{GM}{r}$, this reduces to the usual expression $J=(GMr)^{1/2}$.

My question is: How to derive the above general expression of the angular momentum?

Comment: BTW, specific angular momentum is often denoted by h. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_angular_momentum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\vec J/m = \vec p/m\times \vec r$$

For a circular orbit:

$$ J/m=pr/m=vr$$

Also for a circle, the acceleration is:

$$ a = \frac{2\pi v}T $$

with the period:

$$ T = \frac{2\pi r}v$$

so

$$ a = v^2/r$$

or

$$ v = \sqrt{ar}$$

Based on the potential:

$$ a=\frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial r}=\frac{GM}{r^2}$$

so

$$ v = \sqrt{\frac{GM}{r^2}r}$$

Hence:

$$J/m = rv =  \sqrt{\frac{GM}{r^2}r^3}= \sqrt{GMr}$$